# Calculating probability with help of characteristic function

Tags: probability, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be integer valued with Characteristic Function $\phi$. How to show that

$\ P(|X| = k)= \frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} e^{ikt} \phi(t) dt$

$P(S_n =k) =\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} e^{ikt} (\phi(t))^n dt $

Comment: What's $S_n$....?

Comment: it is sum of n many i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2,....,X_n$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that $(1)$ is true.

Take the simplest possible example. Let $P(X=1)=p$ and let $P(X=0)=1-p$. Then, for $k=1$
$$P(|X|=1)=p.$$

The [characteristic function of this distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) is $$1-p+pe^{it}.$$

The OP claims that $$p=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} e^{it} (1-p+pe^{it}) dt.$$

But
$$\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} e^{it} (1-p+pe^{it}) dt=0.$$

I suspect then that $(2)$ is not true either -- for the same reason. Note that the characteristic function of $S_n$ is $$(1-p+pe^{it})^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are using the expression for the probability density function, given the characteristic function.  However you are dealing with a discrete distribution, so you must use the expression for the cumulative distribution function from the characteristic function.  See the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29